# HTML file not loading jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I included

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

in my `index.html` header, and script.js is in the same folder as index.html. I have a simple div that is to be resizable in the body section.

script.js has

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").resizable();
});
```

very simple.. but when I load index.html on all browsers the div is not resizable. Is the way im including the js file incorrect?

I'm assuming that I should be able to load index.html and just start resizing the div.

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Resize Me!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you doing this on your local machine?  If yes, do you have a server installed?

Comment: yes, this is all local machine. i have the files in htdocs directory, which is what MAMP uses. im pretty beginner at this so it might not be in correct folder?

Comment: Place `alert('boo')` in script.js. Althrough, you said it is in same folder...

Comment: ^ this works. I get a pop up saying boo

Comment: jQuery stylesheets should be loaded before the jQuery JS gets loaded. Also, check my answer pertaining to your function in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your 'stylesheet.css', are you referencing the jquery UI styles? That may be the problem - the draggable arrow that appears in the bottom right of your resizable element is produced using the jquery UI css.

From jquery UI's website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: it seems though it added extra padding on the sides of the div. is this a side effect?

Comment: If you use the F12 developer tools in your browser and inspect the div, you can see where that extra padding is coming from. Look at the "styles" window on the right. Usually, if a style is inherited from jquery UI css that is undesired, such as extra padding, I will override it with a cascading style.

Answer (score 3):

You're loading the jQuery UI file. You need to load the standard jQuery file as well.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
```

The standard jQuery file allows you to use the selector `$("#div")`, and the function `ready()`. The jQueryUI allows you to use the function `resizeable()`. So  you need to load both.

EDIT: Since you tagged this as [html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5), you can use

```
<script src='script.js'></script>
```

It is assumed the `<script>` is javascript in HTML5.

Comment: It still does not work. I loaded this before script.js as well.

Comment: @James Change the position of script.js so it loads after the ui file.

Comment: i loaded both standard jQuery as well as jQuery UI lines. then loaded script.js, but no result still. i do not have browser extensions running either..

Comment: @James Then please update your question to show us what you are now doing.

Comment: I forgot. You have to also add the jquery ui css page. I'll put that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a few more things to correctly setup the HTML + JS.

```
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

    <link href="Styling/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.10.0.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Add your CSS here -->

    <script src="Scripts/External/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/External/jquery-ui-1.10.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Add your JS here -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id='sizeableDiv'> Resize me! </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What you did is forget to add the styling for the jQuery.

***EDIT*** Found in the documentation a slight variation on the resizable method as well.
After the `<div>` tag, add:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#sizeableDiv" ).resizable( "enable" );
</script>
```

Found this [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-enable).